# ActionScript 3 stage question HELP!

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a 1.swf loads up a another 2.swf, while i doing things inside 2.swf like

1.swf is bigger
2.swf is smaller inside

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);

it keep refer to the parent's stage instead the 2.swf's stage.

Please help out. thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've put enough exclamation marks in your question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one stage object, and it is always inherited from the root. Anytime you can access the property "stage" inside a DisplayObject (Sprite,MovieClip) it's actually just a reference to the root.stage that gets populated whenever that DisplayObject is added to the root stage, or a child of some object that eventually connects to the stage (the display list). The display list is just an object tree of various display objects that are connected to the root stage. Anyway so, about your question, if you just want to listen for events on your loaded swf do something like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

loader.load(new URLRequest("swf2.swf"));

private function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var swf2Clip:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
    swfClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
}

private function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Do something when swf2 is moused out.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now i get it, so it would only have one stage even the swf is inside another. Cheers mate

Comment: No problem just don't forget to mark the question as answered! lol